# Adjust shared Outlook calendar times for interstate display

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

Our desktop support team all have access to a shared calendar, where we publish our locations for the week.

To do this, we create an all day event. In the title, we add our name, and our locations.

I am the only user in my state.  The other people are all interstate. They are 3 hours ahead of us.

Hence their all day events are going from 9pm - 9pm, instead of 12am - 12am.

Hence, their all day events are stretched over two days in the calendar view:
[image: share calendar]

Is there a way I can adjust their calendar entries so they display at their timezone's times, instead of my timezone's? (so they only take up one day of space)

Comment: Has everyone correctly set their time zones?

Comment: Yep. All the other people are in +10 GMT. I'm in +8 GMT. Daylight saving is on in NSW.

Comment: Have you checked under what time zone the appointments were created (Appointment tab, Time Zones button)? You might add a screenshot for one problematic appointment.

Comment: Does [Outlook's Appointments and Time Zones](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/appointments-and-time-zones/) help?

Comment: To turn on dual time zone display, go to Tools, Options, Preferences tab, Calendar Options, Time Zone button and add a second time zone. Now when you view the calendar in a day planner format, you’ll see two time scales displayed. You can right click on the scale and choose Time zones.. to change zones or swap them.

Comment: Almost fixed it @DavidPostill. It it the all day events at the top of the calendar I'd like to change the display of, not the events of several hours duration in the main display of the calendar.

Comment: The adjustment I would suggest is that, instead of all-day events, everyone posts appointments that cover their working hours for that day.  This gives you the added benefit of knowing availabilities of the team, not just their locations.

Comment: To be fair, their workdays ~are~ from 9pm to 9pm your time :) I like Foosh's suggestion.

Comment: Oh, and when you post your availability, you could always post in their timezone - ie, click the timezone button and change the timezone to their timezone before ticking "all day event". Then just work off head office's timezone for that calendar, as per the suggestion for dual timezones.

Comment: Foosh's suggestion appears to be the way Microsoft suggest this be worked around: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/262451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since migrated to another computer with Office 2013 installed, and the symptom does not occur in Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this too when dealing with workgroups that span EST/PST... It appears to be a limitation in the way Outlook handles "all day" as a special case of midnight to midnight. I've spent some time trying to solve it and come to the same conclusions mentioned in the comments.

I understand the Microsoft lock-in is probably in play, but for what its worth, other products may handle this better. I know Google Calendar is smart enough to understand that an all-day event takes place on a given date (in any/all timezones) and ignores the time component altogether.